# Why does nextcloud not work after dist upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: apache-http-server, php, ubuntu-18.04, nextcloud

I recently did a dist upgrade on my nextcloud machine form Ubuntu 16.04 to Ubuntu 18.04.
After that I got an "Internal Server Error" when trying to access nextcloud. I didn't find anything in the Apache logs, so I searched with `cat /var/log/syslog | grep PHP` any relevant information on PHP errors.
I found:

```
    PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/apcu.so' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/apcu.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
    PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/zip.so' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/zip.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

I checked for the package `php-zip` and found it to be installed for php7.2 which was the version of php referred to by Ubuntu (checked with `php -v`).

I could find the reason why Libraries where not used. I want to share the solution, so anyone else in this case can solve it more easily.

Answer (score 1):

I created a info.php:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

to find that Apache was using php7.0 instead of php7.2.
The fix then was pretty simple:

```
sudo a2enmod php7.2
sudo a2dismod php7.0
sudo service apache2 restart
```

After that nextcloud worked as expected. I found it strange that the dist upgrade didn't ensure that apache was using the most recent version of php. I hope this helps someone in trouble :)